# A word for somebody who is familiar with the ocean?

Tags: single-word-requests

Not looking for a word like "sailor" or "pirate"

Comment: You mean an oceanographer? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/oceanographer

Comment: If you could add some more details about the context, maybe you'll receive better answers. What kind of familiarity do you want to convey?

Comment: found this : [famous sailor's](https://www.google.com/search?q=famous+sailors&rlz=1C1GGLS_en-GBGB359GB359&oq=famous+sailors&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4328j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - it might give you some inspiration

Comment: Need context, but an _old salt_ is one term.

Comment: And along similar lines, a _sea dog_.

Comment: able seaman, admiral, fish (not a person admittedly)

Answer (score 0):

Given the exclusion of "sailor" and "pirate", OP seems to have in mind a familiarity with the ocean that comes from time on ships. I suggest:

**[nautical](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nautical)** - which is associated both with "sailors" and the "sea"/oceans, so generally for matters maritime. As OED glosses it (as first entry):

> Of, relating to, or characteristic of sailing, sailors, or the sea; naval, marine, maritime, seafaring.

Surveying the [usage as found by Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=nautical&gws_rd=cr&ei=4-0SWbGUIcmOgAbNlYfwCA), this sense seems fairly common. However, it has to be said that using this word "for somebody" is now infrequent, thus OED's second entry:

> A nautical person or writer; a sailor. Now *arch*. and *rare*.